# Spark: Inconsistent performance number in scaling number of cores

Tags: performance, apache-spark, hadoop, profiling, benchmarking

I am doing a simple scaling test on Spark using sort benchmark -- from 1 core, up to 8 cores. I notice that 8 cores is slower than 1 core.

```
//run spark using 1 core
spark-submit --master local[1] --class john.sort sort.jar data_800MB.txt data_800MB_output

//run spark using 8 cores
spark-submit --master local[8] --class john.sort sort.jar data_800MB.txt data_800MB_output
```

The input and output directories in each case, are in HDFS.

> 1 core:   80 secs
>
> 8 cores: 160 secs

I would expect 8 cores performance to have x amount of speedup.

Comment: Provide information about your CPU, benchmark sources and results for other steps

Comment: are you seeing all the cores used from spark UI ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Theoretical limitations**

I assume you are familiar [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law) but here is a quick reminder. Theoretical *speedup* is defined as followed :

[image]

where :

- *s* - is the speedup of the parallel part.
- *p* - is fraction of the program that can be parallelized.

In practice theoretical speedup is always limited by the part that cannot be parallelized and even if *p* is relatively high (0.95) the theoretical limit is quite low:

[image]

(*This file is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license.

Attribution: [Daniels220](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Daniels220) at [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/)*)

Effectively this sets theoretical bound how fast you can get. You can expect that *p* will be relatively high in case [embarrassingly parallel jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) but I wouldn't dream about anything close to 0.95 or higher. This is because

**Spark is a high cost abstraction**

Spark is designed to work on commodity hardware at the datacenter scale. It's core design is focused on making a whole system robust and immune to hardware failures. It is a great feature when you work with hundreds of nodes
and execute long running jobs but it is doesn't scale down very well.

**Spark is not focused on parallel computing**

In practice Spark and similar systems are focused on two problems:

- Reducing overall IO latency by distributing IO operations between multiple nodes.
- Increasing amount of available memory without increasing the cost per unit.

which  are fundamental problems for large scale, data intensive systems.

Parallel processing is more a side effect of the particular solution than the main goal. Spark is distributed first, parallel second. The main point is to keep processing time constant with increasing amount of data by scaling out, not speeding up existing computations.

With modern coprocessors and GPGPUs you can achieve much higher parallelism on a single machine than a typical Spark cluster but it doesn't necessarily help in data intensive jobs due to IO and memory limitations. The problem is how to load data fast enough not how to process it.

**Practical implications**

- Spark is not a replacement for multiprocessing or mulithreading on a single machine.
- Increasing parallelism on a single machine is unlikely to bring any improvements and typically will decrease performance due to overhead of the components.

**In this context**:

Assuming that the class and jar are meaningful and it is indeed a sort it is just cheaper to read data (single partition in, single partition out) and sort in memory on a single partition than executing a whole Spark sorting machinery with shuffle files and data exchange.

Comment: I would add this information: Since Spark would try to split the file, we end up with one of the following scenarios: Either Spark will launch multiple threads to read the same file, at the same time, incurring I/O penalties, by seeking across the input file, instead of reading it linearly. Alternatively, Spark will still read the file in one big gulp, then spread it across the simultaneous jobs, and incur a local shuffle, which would also cost performance. Add to that the mentioned shuffles required by sorting, and performance obviously drops significantly.