# How do I take advantage of my local resources using Spark in local mode?

Tags: java, apache-spark, kotlin, bigdata, cluster-computing

I've been using Apache Spark to write a desktop app which lets you tamper data interactively. I've recently started reading "Learning Spark" and in that the author says that in `local` mode (when master is set to `local`) Spark only uses one `Thread`.

How can I take advantage of all of the cores in my computer without having a full-blown Spark cluster on my computer?

I'm using Java / Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

It defaults to one, but you can specify how many you'd like like so:

```
 val config = SparkConfig()
 config.setMaster("local[8]") // local, using 8 threads (you can vary the number)
 config.setAppName("qwerty")
 val context = SparkContext(config)
```

Comment: That's cool. And how many is recommended per core? Does this mean that just by adding Spark more threads my program will get automatically faster without touching the code?

Comment: I've always used a 1/1 (8 core machine, I set it to 8 spark "cores") but I can't recall anything specific as to why I do it that way. If you were previously just using one I would think you'd see at least some boost in performance; how much likely depends on the use case.

Comment: @AdamArold  _Does this mean that just by adding Spark more threads my program will get automatically faster without touching the code_ - [not really](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41090127/6910411). In general (depending on the data, code and overall configuration) it will keep getting slower and slower :)

Comment: I see. I'm only doing row-based transformations on my `Dataset`s like `replace`, `toLowerCase`, stuff like that. Do I need to touch my code in order to get a speedup?

Comment: Update: I just tested it with `2`, `4` and `8` but it actually slowed down compared to the simple `local` option.