# Librosa feature extraction methods with PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, feature-extraction, spectrogram, librosa

I've been searching long time but can't see any implementation about music feature extraction techniques (like [spectral centroid](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.spectral_centroid.html?highlight=spectral%20centroid#librosa.feature.spectral_centroid), [spectral bandwidth](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.spectral_bandwidth.html?highlight=spectral%20bandwidth#librosa.feature.spectral_bandwidth) etc.) integrated with Apache Spark. I am working with these feature extraction techniques and the process takes a lot of time for music. I want to parallelize and accelerate this process by using Spark. I did some works but couldn't get any speed up. I want to get arithmetic mean and standard deviation of spectral centroid method. This is what I've done so far.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import librosa
import numpy as np
import time

parts=4
print("Parts: ", parts)
sc = SparkContext('local['+str(parts)+']', 'pyspark tutorial')

def spectral(iterator):
    l=list(iterator)
    cent=librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(np.array(l), hop_length=256)
    ort=np.average(cent)
    std=np.std(cent)
    return (ort, std) 

y, sr=librosa.load("classical.00080.au")  #This loads the song.

start1=time.time()
normal=librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(np.array(y), hop_length=256)  #This is normal technique without spark
end1=time.time()

print("\nOrt: \t", np.average(normal))
print("Std: \t", np.std(normal))
print("Time elapsed: %.5f" % (end1-start1))

#This is where my spark implementation appears.
rdd = sc.parallelize(y)
start2=time.time()
result=rdd.mapPartitions(spectral).collect()
end2=time.time()
result=np.array(result)

total_avg, total_std = 0, 0
for i in range(0, parts*2, 2):
    total_avg += result[i]
    total_std += result[i+1]
spark_avg = total_avg/parts
spark_std = total_std/parts

print("\nOrt:", spark_avg)
print("Std:", spark_std)
print("Time elapsed: %.5f" % (end2-start2))
```

The output of the program is below.

```
Ort:     971.8843380584146
Std:     306.75410601230413
Time elapsed: 0.17665

Ort:     971.3152955225721
Std:     207.6510740703993
Time elapsed: 4.58174
```

So, even though I parallelized the array y (the array of music signal), I can't speed up the process. It takes longer time. I couldn't understand why. I am newbie with Spark concept. I thought to use GPU for this process but couldn't implement that either. Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Spark: Inconsistent performance number in scaling number of cores](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41090127/8371915)

Comment: Spark is *not* about parallelization of processes in a single machine; if your data can indeed fit into the memory of your single machine, involving Spark will most probably make the implementation *slower*. Spark is about big data sets that cannot fit into the main memory of a single machine, thus parallelizing the process across a *cluster* of many machines...

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Comment: See this [Databricks blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/05/03/benchmarking-apache-spark-on-a-single-node-machine.html) for a use case involving single node computation.