# Spark performance reduced with increased number of worker nodes

Tags: performance, apache-spark

I have a spark application which loads data from csv files, calls Drools engine, uses flatmap and saves results to output files (.csv)

Below are the two test cases :

1) When I am running this Application with **2 Worker nodes** having same configuration (8 cores) Application takes **5.2 minutes** to complete :

- No. Of Executors : 133
- Total No of Cores : 16
- Used Memory : 2GB( 1GB per executor)
- Available Memory : 30GB

2) When I am running this Application with **3 Worker nodes** having same configuration (8 cores) Application takes **7.6 minutes** to complete :

- No. Of Executors : 266
- Total No of Cores : 24
- Used Memory : 3GB( 1GB per executor)
- Available Memory : 45GB

**Expected result**

It should take less time after adding one more worker node with same configuration.

**Actual Result**

It takes more time after adding one more worker node with same configuration.

I am running application using `spark-submit` command in **standalone** mode.

Here I want to understand that why increasing worker node doesn't increase the performance, is that not the correct expectation?

**EDIT**

After looking at other similar question on stackoverflow I tried running application with `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true`, however it further degrades the performance.

Comment: [Spark: Inconsistent performance number in scaling number of cores](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41090127/8371915)

Comment: @user8371915 Thanks for pointing out, however problem in that question is having same machine and increased number of cores(that's why in solution he mentioned multithreading on single machine), in my case machines are multiple(worker nodes are 2 in first case and 3 in second case) , is that solution still remain applicable in my case?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing similar problems.